# Android device is stuck on "signing in" page

Tags: google

I had my tablet repaired yesterday (new LCD) - unfortunately the tablet had been sitting broken for a long time.  When I got it back, I done a factory reset  so that I could start fresh.  The factory reset was successful but now it gets stuck on the signing in page when I try to sign in with my google account.  It's the vodafone 3G tablet.  It has been upgraded to 4.4.2 android version.  I cannot access anything to do with google.  And the play store keeps giving notifications that it is not working.  There is no data or cache to clear, I tried stopping it from the settings but it still keeps happening.  I have tried whatever I know to try but just can't get in.  I would greatly appreciate any assistance.  Thank you.

Comment: connect to wifi or insert SIM card with mobile data and wait for update. or install update.zip from stock recovery

Comment: Wonder if it has something to do with unsupported TLS/SSL on older Android versions.

Comment: Android 4.4 devices support TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 (TLS1.2 is also supported but disabled by default). All Google services should still support TLS 1.0 e.g. [accounts.google.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=accounts.google.com&s=172.217.6.45) [play.google.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=play.google.com&s=142.250.191.78) and [play.googleapis.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=play.googleapis.com&s=142.250.189.170). Therefore TLS version should not be a problem. Make sure date and time is correctly set on your tablet.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I will try these and hopefully it works.

Comment: Is the ROM modified (e.g. rooted)? If yes you can try to register your GSF-ID at Google. The whole process is described here: https://lineageos.org/Google-Play-Certification/

Comment: Thank you everybody.  Unfortunately I still can't get it working.  I will have to take it to somebody.

Comment: It might be google released some broken update (again) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242689